# SQL code unable to display attendance in percentage format

Tags: sql

I am having trouble adding the condition to only show those with attendance less than 81..

```
SELECT Absence.StudentID AS StudentNumber,
   Student.NAME AS "Student Name",
   Subject.NAME AS "Subject Name",
   CONVERT(VARCHAR, 100 - (100 * count(*) / 10)) AS 'Attendance(%)'
FROM Absence,
   Subject,
   Student,
   (
      SELECT COUNT(*) AS tot
      FROM Absence
      ) x
WHERE Subject.SubjectCode = Absence.SubjectCode
   AND Student.StudentNumber = Absence.StudentID
GROUP BY Absence.StudentID,
   Subject.NAME,
   Student.NAME;
```

The above is the code that displays exactly what I want but I cannot add in the condition only. My Attendance(%) is already int right? So using the CAST or CONVERT does not work either. It says it has trouble converting.

Comment: What condition are you trying to add and what happens whne you try?  Oh by the way, you need double quotes, not single quotes around your percentage alias.

Answer (score 1):

It is an inplicit data-type casting in your math

`select 
    100/50 as intMath 
,   100.00/50.00 as nbrMath`

Comment: opps - Got my numerator and denominator reversed, but the concept is the same, use 100.00 instead of 100 in your math.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to get a percent, it's multiplied by 100 and is a DECIMAL, which doesn't appear to be how your code works:

```
SELECT (CAST(9 AS DECIMAL(5,2))/CAST(10 AS DECIMAL(5,2)))*CAST(100 AS DECIMAL(5,2))
-- Returns 90.00

SELECT (CAST(9 AS INT)/CAST(10 AS INT))*CAST(100 AS INT)
-- Returns 0
```

Using your OP example:

```
SELECT CAST(100 AS DECIMAL(5,2)) - ((CAST(100 AS DECIMAL(5,2)) * CAST(8 AS DECIMAL(5,2))) / CAST(10 AS DECIMAL(5,2)))
-- Returns 20.00

-- Formatted with a percent:
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(100 AS DECIMAL(5,2)) - ((CAST(100 AS DECIMAL(5,2)) * CAST(8 AS DECIMAL(5,2))) / CAST(10 AS DECIMAL(5,2))) AS VARCHAR(25)),1,5) + '%'
```

**Note: this applies to `SQL Server`**.  90% is .9, which is treated as 0 when it's `CAST AS INT`.